# Почему chromedriver использует так много места?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, chromedriver

Запуская скрипт, использующий selenium, становится занято ~100мб места на диске с хромом. Скрипт во время работы будет создавать и уничтожать примерно 50к хромдрайверов, но похоже, они оставляют за собой временные файлы. Где они хранятся? Как удалить их после закрытия хромдрайвера прямо в коде?

Answer (score 0):

Хром создаёт временный профиль для каждого запуска хромодрайвер. Этот профиль распалагается в папке Тэмп обычно и удаляется при закрытии хрома.

Comment: Как его увидеть? И если удаляет, почему место не освобождается?

Comment: Ос какая? Виндовс?

Comment: да, windows 10 pro